# Dynamics CRM. Delete row from subgrid using JS

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics

How can I delete a row from a subgrid using Javascript?

```
    var grid = Xrm.Page.getControl("Produktrader").getGrid();
    grid.getRows().forEach(function (row) {
        var rowData = row.getData();
        if (rowData != null) {
              //delete row here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to delete the record in JavaScript you will need to make a REST call to delete the record from the database, and then refresh the page. You can't just delete the record from the subgrid.

[Sample: Create, retrieve, update, and delete using the OData endpoint with JavaScript and jQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309549(v=crm.6).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

I'll add to James' answer in that after you perform the Delete, you should trigger a subgrid refresh via javascript

```
Xrm.Page.getControl("Produktrader").refresh();
```